# Tutorial Luiztools | Error 404: CRUD in Node.js with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The project is on my github:
https://github.com/vabmoni/luiztools

I followed this tutorial:
https://www.luiztools.com.br/post/tutorial-crud-em-node-js-com-driver-nativo-do-mongodb/
but when I edit the customer, I have an error 404.

To run the project:

Install MongoDB Server

Add MongoDB /bin folder to PATH

Open first CMD: mongod --dbpath C:{Your Path}\webapp\data

Open second CMD: mongo

Open third CMD: npm install and npm start

**routes/index.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const docs = await global.db.findAll();
    res.render('index', { title: 'Lista de Clientes', docs });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});

router.get('/new', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('new', { title: 'Novo Cadastro', doc: { "nome": "", "idade": "" }, action: '/new' });
})

router.post('/new', async (req, res, next) => {
  const nome = req.body.nome;
  const idade = parseInt(req.body.idade);

  try {
    const result = await global.db.insert({ nome, idade });
    console.log(result);
    res.redirect('/');
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});

router.post('/edit/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const nome = req.body.nome;
  const idade = parseInt(req.body.idade);

  try {
    const result = await global.db.update(id, { nome, idade });
    console.log(result);
    res.redirect('/');
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});

router.get('/delete/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  try {
    const result = await global.db.deleteOne(id);
    console.log(result);
    res.redirect('/');
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

**views/index.ejs**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <ul>
      <% docs.forEach(function(customer){ %>
        <li>
          <a href="/edit/<%= customer._id %>">
            <%= customer.nome %>
          </a>
          <a href="/delete/<%= customer._id %>" 
            onclick="return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja excluir?');">
            X
          </a>
        </li>
      <% }) %>
    </ul>
    <hr />
    <a href="/new">Cadastrar novo cliente</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

**views\new.ejs**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <form action="<%= action %>" method="POST">
      <p>Nome:<input type="text" name="nome" value="<%= doc.nome %>" /></p>
      <p>Idade:<input type="number" name="idade" value="<%= doc.idade %>" /></p>
      <input type="submit" value="Salvar" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**db.js**

```js
const mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost")
    .then(conn => global.conn = conn.db("webapp"))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))

function findAll() {
    return global.conn.collection("customers").find().toArray();
}

function insert(customer) {
    return global.conn.collection("customers").insertOne(customer);
}

const ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId;
function findOne(id) {
    return global.conn.collection("customers").findOne(new ObjectId(id));
}

function update(id, customer) {
    return global.conn.collection("customers").updateOne({ _id: new ObjectId(id) }, { $set: customer });
}

function deleteOne(id) {
    return global.conn.collection("customers").deleteOne({ _id: new ObjectId(id) });
}
 
module.exports = { findAll, insert, findOne, update, deleteOne }
```

Comment: the uri of editing is  localhost:3000/edit/:id ?

Comment: exactly, the uri of editing is localhost:3000/edit/:id

Comment: whats the output of `console.log(result);` in `/edit/:id` ?

Comment: GET /edit/61337c21900415ca43123fdb 404 2.634 ms - 983. Do I need to take out the try catch block?

Comment: use POST insted of GET

Comment: `router.post('/edit/:id', async (req, res) => {` you should send data via `POST` method not GET

Comment: are you using post man  ?

Comment: But as you see, the code is written router.post and not router.get

Comment: for editing customer use send data with postMan ?

Comment: It worked through postman

Comment: so add your client code

Comment: I ask for a solution to edit the customer by the localhost:3000 and not thorugh postman, can you help? Try to download the project and run with mongodb

Comment: did you mean edit by browser ?

Comment: yes, please can you help?

Comment: browser sends GET request , you could fetch list of data by browser not editing

Comment: ok. Because I am a novice developer, i will wait the answer I can't do it by myself. thanks for telling me to use postman